# What is meant by the phrase "as time evolves"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard this in a company presentation today and I thought it was just some random words, but I looked it up on a search engine and found it in lots of papers and other random sites.  So it appears to be a phrase in common use.

Does it mean, "as time goes on" or "as time changes things". If not, does the word "evolves" mean something different and it's just the wrong word to use in the sentence that sounds right to some and has come to be used in common parlance?

Comment: Yes, time does not evolve, things do over time. It's like *the reason why* instead of *the reason that* as far as useless but harmless repetition.

Comment: OED might have a 'roll on' sense, but it looks like a transferred usage to me.

Comment: People don't always speak in perfect sentences. Yes, this means: as time goes on. Everyone here needs to take a breath. It's not as if in every discussion any of you has had in your life, you haven't used a term, which on second thought and in writing, is perhaps not the best one.

Comment: The expression actually took off from the mid-60s and is still currently used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+time+evolves&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20time%20evolves%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's a popular expression in the sciences, especially for "as time increases" in a process, an equation representing a process, its graph, etc.

Comment: Time _proceeds_ or _time passes_. It does not 'evolve'. 'Evolve' implies that something is unfolding or developing as time passes. But time _itself_ does not. The fact that many people misuse the word and misapply the concept does not make it correct.

Comment: It's blather, meant to make the speaker sound erudite on the cheap. Of course time doesn't evolve. That those who know better routinely violate the meaning of this word says something.